# How to create a list from a text fille using SH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to create a SH script that reads a file that contains a list of directories

```
dirA
dirB
dirC
```

And use this information to generate a command like this:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out dirA dirB dirC
```

The package file is called `.package-list`  and this is the script I have at the moment:

```sh
while read package;
do
  go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./$package
done <.package-list
```

The problem is that that script executes the `go test` command three times:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./dirA
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./dirB
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./dirC
```

What can I do to read the file and generate a command like I need it?

Comment: Use the `xargs` command

Answer (score 2):

If using `bash` instead of `sh` (You have both tagged, so it's not clear which shell you're targeting), you can read the lines of the file into an array:

```sh
readarray -t packages < .package-list
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out "${packages[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs`

```
xargs go test -coverprofile=coverage.out < .package-list
```

Comment: Mind `xargs`' argument splitting and quoting mechanisms. For GNU xargs use `xargs -d \\n …` to make this safe. For other implementations use `sed 's/./\\&/' file | xargs …`. You might also want to add `-x`.

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn’t crazy big, you can read the entire file in all at once into an array, provided none of the directory names themselves contain a line feed:

```
IFS=$'\n'  # To split on new lines only
dirs=( $(<.package-list) )
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out "${dirs[@]}"
```

Comment: Weeell, it's no sense to use array then, just `IFS=$'\n' ; go test -coverprofile=coverage.out $(<.package-list)`

Comment: In bash, you could even disable globs using `set -o noglob` to make this safe in case of special characters like `*?[]`.

Comment: So true, @KamilCuk.  I actually expected one to be able to set a temporary value for`IFS` by way of `IFS=$'\n' go test -coverprofile=coverage.out $(<.package-list)`, but apparently not.

Comment: Another good suggest, @Socowi

Comment: Yeah, sadly `IFS=... cmd1 $(cmd2)` does not work, because `IFS` is only set for `cmd1`'s environment, but not for the current shell in which `cmd1 $(cmd2)` is executed. To make the changes to `IFS` and `set` local, you can use a subshell: `( IFS=$'\n'; set -o noglob; go test ...; )`.

Comment: Obviously, @Socowi.  That’s not really what I was getting at, and it felt like we were improving on whichever suggestion came before, but you’ve just broken the chain now.  We _could_ also store the `IFS` value, and reset it later, or run the command with `bash -c`, or wrap it inside a function and declare a `local`.  Or just stop using `bash` and switch to `FiSH`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out $(cat .package-list | tr '\n' ' ')
```